# How to plot a straight line in d3.js by user interaction

Tags: d3.js

I want to draw lines depending upon user clicks. that is the user will click on starting point of somewhere and ending point of some where I want to draw a straight line between this points. Is there anyway to do this in  d3.js. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can draw line by mouse clicking, you can use `e.clientX` and `e.clientY`

```
container.onclick = function (e) {
    xPosition[i] = e.clientX;
    yPosition[i] = e.clientY;
}
```

Get the X, Y positions as array and pass the array to SVG line attributes as

```
var line = svgContainer.append("line")
        .attr("x1", xPosition[i - 1])
        .attr("y1", yPosition[i - 1])
        .attr("x2", xPosition[i])
        .attr("y2", yPosition[i])
```

This will help you [jsfiddle-draw line by click](http://jsfiddle.net/thanushcst/r14hr7zs/3/)

Comment: Nice fiddle. I want a straight line anyways.

Comment: If you want only the single straight line, just remove the previous line using "d3.select("line").remove(line)".
Check this updated one http://jsfiddle.net/thanushcst/r14hr7zs/4/